# not null usage in mysql

Tags: mysql

I use syntax like `name varchar(20) NOT NULL` in mysql..i have a big confusion over here.

typically does it mean that this field is mandatory?

but when i store a space in this field it accepts it.is it correct. its like while insert i say `'".$_POST['name']."'`. even if the name does not have any value query is executed.

can any1 just clarify me on this ?

is NULL and blank space same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to explain NULL to you again, the others have done that.

When doing SQL with PHP, please, always try to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Example

```
$name = (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ? NULL : $_POST['name'];
```

This says, if your $_POST is either not set, or empty, set the value of $name to NULL. Otherwise use $_POST['name'].

Now, when you bind $name in your prepared SQL statement, you will either have a strict NULL value or the string of the name.

Comment: "When doing SQL with PHP, please, always try to use PDO." Why?

Comment: PDO provides a powerful data-access abstraction layer, it's built in since 5.1, so you can ensure you have less-buggy code than if you write it yourself.

Prepared statements run faster, if the same SQL query is run multiple times in a page load with only the variables changing. The database can bypass the analyze, compile and optimization of the query and just sub in values.

Last, it provides "automatic" SQL Injection safety, as you do not escape the query's parameters, but the PDO itself takes care of it for you.

Comment: Why using `!isset($_POST['name']`? empty() won't check !isset()too?

Comment: Ali, it's just another defensive programming practise. Empty will report that a variable, that is not officially declared, as empty. So there is a scenario where you can be checking empty($var), which would evaluate to true, but $var was never declared. isset formally checks if you've set a value. http://ca2.php.net/empty

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` and an empty string are not the same. You can store an empty string in a column that is defined as `NOT NULL`.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> A common error when working with NULL  is to assume that it is not possible to insert a zero or an empty string into a column defined as NOT NULL, but this is not the case. These are in fact values, whereas NULL means “not having a value.” You can test this easily enough by using IS [NOT] NULL as shown:

```
mysql> SELECT 0 IS NULL, 0 IS NOT NULL, '' IS NULL, '' IS NOT NULL;
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| 0 IS NULL | 0 IS NOT NULL | '' IS NULL | '' IS NOT NULL |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
|         0 |             1 |          0 |              1 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

> Thus it is entirely possible to insert a zero or empty string into a NOT NULL column, as these are in fact NOT NULL. See Section B.5.5.3, [Problems with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html).

Answer (score 2):

NOT NULL means that the database requires some value to be entered.  It's possible to define a default value in MySQL that will be inserted instead if you try to insert a NULL.

Keep in mind that a space or a blank string is different than NULL.  NULL means that no value at all has been specified, not even blank.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that the value must be provided on insertion. However, MySQL [treats empty strings and NULL differently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html). (And a good thing too, IMO.) From that document:

> A common error when working with NULL
>   is to assume that it is not possible
>   to insert a zero or an empty string
>   into a column defined as NOT NULL, but
>   this is not the case. These are in
>   fact values, whereas NULL means “not
>   having a value.” You can test this
>   easily enough by using IS [NOT] NULL
>   as shown:

```
mysql> SELECT 0 IS NULL, 0 IS NOT NULL, '' IS NULL, '' IS NOT NULL;
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| 0 IS NULL | 0 IS NOT NULL | '' IS NULL | '' IS NOT NULL |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
|         0 |             1 |          0 |              1 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

> Thus it is entirely possible to insert a zero or empty string into a NOT NULL column, as these are in fact NOT NULL.

Comment: OKie i got ur point ... i want all rows which have no value for name in ma db. i should both rite . like ($row['name'] = NULL || $row['name'] = "")  ??

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is actually "`NULL`" and not a blank space. You have to do something like `name=NULL` in order to set a field to null.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the absence of value - an unknown.  A space, or even an empty string, is still something - a string.